# Force the usage of a bin folder

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a larger ASP.NET Core project which means that a lot of DLLs are included in the publish.

Since all of the DLLs are placed in the root folder it's cumbersome to navigate the   folder structure (to mange configs etc) due to the sheer amount of files.

Is it possible to tell ASP.NET Core that it should load all assemblies from another folder (`bin\`)?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Not yet. I would like to move the bin folder without having to do too much configuration. For instance "Kudu" in Azure complains on too many files in the webroot.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in opposite side. If your problem is just config files then relocate them into config folder and keep them there. As of now dotnet will publish your project + framework (if you use self contained flag).

You can configure aspnetcore to use files

```
config.AddJsonFile("config/appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
```

So then that folder will be on top and better accessible

Yes in root folder there still be web.config but in my project that file usually is same for all environments. But again it depends where you deploy, because if you deploy to non IIS environment then you don't even need it

Answer (score 1):

Hi How about the **Managed Extensibility Framework** , It allows you load assemblies dynamically.

Use BuildManager to load assemblies dynamically,

```
string pluginPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "plugins");
foreach (string f in Directory.GetDirectories(pluginPath))
{
    string binPath = Path.Combine(f, "bin");
    if (Directory.Exists(binPath))
    {
        foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles(binPath, "*.dll"))
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
            BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly(a);
        }
    }
```

Resolve assemblies using below code,

```
protected virtual void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //...

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
}

System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    var currentAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

    foreach (var assembly in currentAssemblies)
    {
        if (assembly.FullName == args.Name || assembly.GetName().Name == args.Name)
        {
            return assembly;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: But how do I get msbuild to output all assemblies to the bin folder? Many of the assemblies comes from indirectly references nuget packages.

Comment: I think you can use the classic Copy task in the AfterBuild target.If you dont want to copy then it should be part of the solution. Otherwise use links in the source tree.